# Internal sheet name as variable based on input in excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code:

```
    Sub test()
    Dim Variable As String
    Variable = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
    Sheet2.Select
    Range(Variable).Select
    End Sub

Value in cell A1 = B2:B3
```

The code works perfectly so far. Now I want to make the "Sheet2" part as a variable in the same way as I did for the range. I want to write the internal sheet name into an excel cell to make it variable. I tried the following way so far but it did not work.

```
    Sub test()
    Dim Variable As String
    Variable = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
    Variable2 = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
    Variable2.Select
    Range(Variable).Select
    End Sub

Value in cell A1 = B2:B3
Value in cell A2 = Sheet2
```

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221568%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

```
Sheets(Variable2).Range(Variable).Select
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to get the Sheetname by entering the Codename, use a function like this to return the right sheet name:

```
Function getSheet(codename_ As String) As String
'returns the Sheet name corresponding to the Codename
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.codename = codename_ Then

        getSheet = ws.Name
        Exit Function
    End If
Next ws
End Function
```

Then you can use this like `Sheets(getSheet("CODENAME")).Select`

Answer (score -1):

try with below code

```
Sub test()
    Dim Variable As String
    Variable = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
    Variable2 = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
    Worksheets(Variable2).Select
    Range(Variable).Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT - 1**

```
Sheets(Val(Replace(variable2, "Sheet", ""))).Select
```

Comment: Hi Karthick, thanks for your answer. The only issue is that I want to refer to the INTERNAL sheet name in vba and not to the name it has in the excel front-end view. For example when I rename the Sheet2 to for example "Input" your code does not run anymore. The internal sheet name would remain Sheet2; therefore, I want to use the internal name in my code. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: HI Karthick, I have changed the code to the following but it does not work :-(                                                                                                   Sub test()
    Dim Variable As String
    Variable = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
    variable2 = Sheet2.Range("A2").Value
    Sheets(Val(Replace(variable2, "Sheet", ""))).Select
    Range(Variable).Select
End Sub

Comment: its working at my side. in which line the error occurs?